# How to use onClick to fire two functions reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, eventhandler, react-props

Fairly new to React Js so bear with me...

I'm using onClick in a child component to change the state of a parent component. The parent state is a boolean which, in turn is used to toggle a class on and off on a seperate element from that which was clicked. Something like this:

### In Parent.js (relevant code only):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        elementOpen: false;
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        elementOpen: !this.state.bucketListOpen
    })
}

render() {
     return (
         <Child 
             className = {this.state.elementOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
             toggleClassName = {this.handleClick}
         />
     )
}
```

### In Child.js (relevant code only):

```
render() {
     return (
         <div>
             <div className={this.props.className}>Test</div>
             <a onClick={this.props.toggleClassName}>Click Me</a>
         </div>
     )
}
```

... and this works fine. No problems. The problem arises when I want to move the {this.props.toggleClassName} in the Child component into a handling function (the reason is so that I can fire more than one event on click). In short, it ceases to work.

I've tried creating a method in the Child component and placing the prop inside the method as follows:

```
handleClassSwitch() {
    return this.props.toggleClassName;
}  

render() {
    return (
         <div>
             <div className={this.props.className}>Test</div>
             <a onClick={this.handleClassSwitch}>Click Me</a>
         </div>
    )
}
```

...but sadly it's not working and I'm stumped. Probably really obvious but I'm struggling here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call multiple functions inside `handleClassSwitch`, but you need to call those methods by using `()`.

Like this:

```
handleClassSwitch() {
   this.props.toggleClassName();    // notice ()
   function2();
   function3();
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to bind `handleClassSwitch` method inside Child component, either bind inside constructor or use arrow function.

Check this snippet for the difference between these two:

```js
function abc() {
  console.log('calling abc');
  return 1;
}

console.log('without () => ', abc);
console.log('with () => ', abc());
```

Comment: Lovely - issue was the () at the end of the function call (doh!) - thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently not binding your `handleClassSwitch` function the same way you do with `handleClick` in your `Parent` component.

It will work if you bind it in the `Child` component as well. You could also make `handleClassSwitch` into an arrow function if your would prefer.

```
class Child {
  handleClassSwitch = () => {
    this.props.toggleClassName();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.props.className}>Test</div>
        <a onClick={this.handleClassSwitch}>Click Me</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I has actually bound it but didn;t put it in the code in the question - my mistake.

Comment: @Stef Ah, alright. Then it's probably just a matter of calling `toggleClassName` in `handleClassSwitch`: `this.props.toggleClassName();`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't actually invoke `toggleClassName` anymore. When you click the `a` tag, it calls `handleClassSwitch` which returns a reference to `toggleClassName` instead of invoking it. Try writing this instead:

```
handleClassSwitch = () => {
   this.props.toggleClassName();
}
```

Notice that I use the `=>` syntax to bind the `handleClassSwitch` so it has access to `this`